# filling object property with string directly

Tags: c#

I know how to cast implicity object to string but is it possible to cast string to object property?

I would like to fill object property directly, without using code: `ob.property="text".`

Instead I would like to use: `ob="text"`

Example:

```
class Person 
{
public string Name  { get; set; }

public string Name2  { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }

.

.

.

}




var a=new Person();
```

I would like to fill property Name with string `"text1"`

Is there any way to do this :  `a="text1"` instead of  `a.Name="text1"` ?

I know how to cast implicity object to string but is it possible to cast string to object property?

Comment: `a=text1` does a different thing. so no, you can't. but you can use `indexer`.  `public string this[int i] => Name;` and `a[any number]="text1"`

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can achieve this is using implicit operators overload.

For example,

```
class Person 
{

public string Name  { get; set; }
public static implicit operator string(Person person)
{
    return person.Name;
}

public static implicit operator Person(string name)
{
    return new Person(){Name=name};
}
}
```

Now you can assign as

```
var person = new Person();
person = "Test Name";
```

But you would need to evaluate whether this effort is worth it.

Comment: Then are you not changing the behavior of the object? which name this is referring to?

Comment: Obviously Name and not Name2. I think the second Name is a typo, surely there cannt be two name properties

Comment: Well why not? What if there is a nick name and a real name?

Comment: I meant the "Name" property. You cannot quite have multiple string implicit conversion.

Comment: btw, what do you mean by "not changing the behavior of object" ? What behaviour do you intend to change w.r.t to OP ?

Comment: The nearest solution is this Anu gave, but it does not solve the problem, as it returns new Person object with correct Name property, but I am loosing other properties of person.

It is theoretical example, but I can imagine you can have class which has one dominant property (major) and all other properties which are minor, so I can create first, object, set all minor properties and later in the code I will have to work only on this one major property.

Comment: @kris Could you describe why you need such a feature in first place ? may be there are other alternatives we could think then ?

Comment: It is not critical question , and it can be solved  using property of object . I was just curious if in C# is casting mechanism from simple type to object. Something similar to your solution , but without returning new object.  Just similar to other way casting: object to simple type.  As an example I can imagine new  class doubleCustom,  where major property would be the value of double type, and it may store more assisting properties like Unit, Desription, Comment, ....  But in the code it would be used as just in similar way as simple double type.

Answer (score 0):

While it is a stupid idea, you could use a bit of reflection and as @Bizhan said an indexer to achieve something similar.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();

        mc[0] = "Test Name";
        mc[1] = "Test Surname";
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public string this[int i]
        {
            set
            {
                var props = this.GetType().GetProperties();
                props[i + 1].SetValue(this, value);
            }
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Surname { get; private set; }
    }
```

The only problem with this is that it'll only work on String types, the indexer must be first in the class, exception will be thrown when property index will be outside available number of properties, it uses index based property access but that could be automated using a for loop. Then again you could modify this code to do various checks.

It still makes no reason why one would need this - if you explain your use case better there might be better ways to go on about your problem.